# issue with 2 select dropdowns on 1 page

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, joomla, html-select

I have an issue in Joomla where I have a module that creates a select dropdown list from a menu.

Works great if I have just 1 dropdown on a page - if I have 2 dropdowns by creating another instance of the module pulling from another menu (i.e. dropdown1 & dropdown2) the page crashes.

I was wondering if it is to do with the following code in my modules default.php tmpl file:

```
<?php
// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<form name="SelMenFrm">
<?php if($params->get('showLabel') == 1) echo $params->get('selectLabel')."&nbsp;"; ?>
<select name="SelMenSel" class="<?php echo $class_sfx;?>" onchange="javascript:location.href=document.SelMenFrm.SelMenSel.options[document.SelMenFrm.SelMenSel.selectedIndex].value;">
<option><?php echo $params->get('topText');?></option>
<?php
foreach ($list as $i => &$item) :
    // Determine if item shoud be set as selected
    $selected = "";
    if (($item->home == 0) && ($item->id == $active_id)) $selected = "selected=\"selected\"";
    // Set indent
    if ($item->level == 1) $indent = "";
    if ($item->level == 2) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 3) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 4) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 5) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 6) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    echo "<option ".$selected."value=\"".$item->flink."\">".$indent.$item->title."</option>";
endforeach;
?>
</select></form>
```

Any ideas/help would be really appreciated ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$indent = str_repeat("&nbsp;",($item->level>=1?($item->level-1):0));
```

what about that?

Comment: i have tried your code in my module menu assignment for "on all pages" not any creshes

Comment: where & how should I implement the $indent code (above)... not being a coder personally ;-)

Comment: **cut this**
`if ($item->level == 1) $indent = "";
    if ($item->level == 2) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 3) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 4) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 5) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";
    if ($item->level == 6) $indent = "&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;";`
**paste this**
`$indent = str_repeat("&nbsp;",($item->level>=1?($item->level-1):0));`

Comment: will the $indent code mean I can place 2 select modules on 1 page?

Answer (score 0):

if you're loading the modules with this code:

```
<select name="SelMenSel" class="<?php echo $class_sfx;?>" onchange="javascript:location.href=document.SelMenFrm.SelMenSel.options[document.SelMenFrm.SelMenSel.selectedIndex].value;"
```

then they can't work, as they would have the same id and onchange is relying on the id to identify the select: document.SelMenFrm.SelMenSel